# How to use bool query with must clause and filter clause in NEST 2.3.0

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

The docs says that Filtered query is

> Deprecated in 2.0.0-beta1. Use the bool query instead with a must
>   clause for the query and a filter clause for the filter.

[source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/filtered-query-usage.html)

Is this a proper use of filter clause?

```
var result = client.Search<Post>(x => x
.Query(q => q
    .Bool(b => b
        .Must(m => m
            .MultiMatch(mp => mp
                .Query(query)
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Fields(f1 => f1.Title, f2 => f2.Body, f3 => f3.Tags))))
        .Filter(f => f
            .Bool(b1 => b1
                .Must(filters)))))); // or filter?
```

query is a `string` and filters is `Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Post>, QueryContainer>[]`

the raw JSON request is:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "javascript",
            "fields": [ "title", "body", "tags" ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "tags": { "value": "javascript" } } },
              { "term": { "tags": { "value": "ajax" } } },
              { "term": { "tags": { "value": "jquery" } } }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What does it yield if you run it?

Answer (score 1):

Where you would have used `filtered` query *query*, you would now use a `bool` query `must` clause and likewise, where you would have used a `filtered` query *filter*, you would now use a `bool` query `filter` clause.

In your case, you have multiple filter clauses that must be satisfied so wrapping as a set of `must` clauses in a `bool` query passed to the outer bool `filter` clause is correct.

In Elasticsearch 2.0, [queries and filters merged into one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#breaking_20_query_dsl_changes), with the notion of a query context and a filter context; when wrapped in a `bool` query `filter` clause, a query/filter is in a filter context so relevance scores will not be calculated and it will be cacheable.

NEST 2.x aligns with the change in Elasticsearch 2.0 and has queries (`QueryContainer`, `QueryContainerDescriptor<T>`, etc.) that can be used in both query and filter contexts.

Comment: So does this mean that even my original query is a should query if i want to apply a filter on my query, I must use "must" query with "filter?

Comment: @batmaci - no. If you have `should` and `must` clauses, these should remain as is. `filter` do not partake in scoring and are _generally_ cached, meaning that they tend to be faster in cases where you want to filter the documents on which a score will be calculated.

Comment: QueryDescriptor<T> is not available in NEST 2.x, @RussCam, Can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136094/what-is-the-alternative-to-querydescriptor-nest-2-x