# What is the alternative to QueryDescriptor nest 2.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We are migrating our Nest 1.0 to NEST 2.0, In previous version we were having a query like this:

```
container = new QueryContainer();
                    container = new QueryDescriptor<BaseModel>().Range(qs => qs.OnField(f => f.PublishedDate).LowerOrEquals(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now)));

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) && !contentType.ToLower().Equals("all"))
                    {
                        container &= new QueryDescriptor<BaseModel>().QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(f => f.ContentType).Query(contentType));
                    }
```

In NEST 2.0 QueryDescriptor Class is not available, How Can we perform similar action in NEST 2.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apply few changes to your code and you will be good:

1. Change `QueryDescriptor<>` to `QueryContainerDescriptor`
2. Use `DateRange(..)` instead of `Range(..)`
3. `OnFields(..)` methods have been changed to `Fields(..)` all around
4. Finally, replace `LowerOrEquals(..)` with `LessThanOrEquals(..)`

Something like:

```
container = new QueryContainer();
container = new QueryContainerDescriptor<BaseModel>().DateRange(qs => qs.Field(f => f.PublishedDate).LessThanOrEquals(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now)));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) && !contentType.ToLower().Equals("all"))
{
    container &= new QueryDescriptor<BaseModel>().QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(f => f.ContentType).Query(contentType));
}
```

Hope it helps.